# SQL Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this table in a Oracle DDBB

```
ASSET  |   LEVELDATA  |   VALUE
1      |    Super1     |   500
1      |    Super2     |   400
2      |    Super1     |   300
2      |    Super2     |   150
3      |    Super1     |   180
3      |    Super2     |   50
```

I need to show:

```
ASSET  |   Super1  |   Super2
1      |    500    |     400
2      |    300    |     150
3      |    180    |      50
```

help please!, and thanks

Comment: Do some research over pivoting in Oracle DB. Show some effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need the pivot operator described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
  (select ASSET  
   from tablename)
   pivot
    (count(ASSET)
      for LEVELDATA  in ('Super1', 'Super2'));
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The pivot operator doesnt work in my SQL editor. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select
    asset,
    max(case when leveldata = 'Super1' then value end) Super1,
    max(case when leveldata = 'Super2' then value end) Super2
 from
   bbdd
 group by
    asset;
```

As indicated by others, you can achieve the same result set with the `pivot` operator:

```
select * from DDBB
pivot (sum(value) for leveldata in ('Super1', 'Super2'))
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30086/3)

Comment: I dont know what i´m doing bad...always show me  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Where do you run the statement?

Comment: I got it!:SELECT asset,
(SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'SuperficieTE' THEN value END)),
(SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'SuperficieCO' THEN value END)),
(CASE 
WHEN (SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'Super1' THEN value END))>=(SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'Super2' THEN value END))
THEN 'TE' 
WHEN (SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'Super1' THEN value END))<(SUM(CASE leveldata WHEN N'Super2' THEN value END))
THEN 'CO'
END) AS "Type"
FROM <TABLE>
AND leveldata IN ('Super1', 'Super2')
group by asset
ORDER BY asset